# How to troubleshoot? Google Chrome Malfunctioning: Console Freezes & Websites Timeout

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I've had intermittent issues with Google Chrome the past month. I'll open a new tab and a page will time out, and the dev console has been freezing on me.

I'm stumped on how to fix it?

**List of things I've done.**

1. Suspected malware, ran Sophos, came up with nothing.
2. Cleared Chrome of all extensions, cache and localStorage.
3. Removed Sync / user profile.
4. Uninstalled & reinstalled (this was before clearing all the saved browser settings)

***I'm on Chrome 63.0.3239.132***

Am I the only one experiencing this?
Any general advice?
Maybe try going down a few browser versions?

Answer (score -1):

Had it happen today this was my fix - I have no idea what the cause was.

Settings -> Advanced -> Reset

Comment: This didn't solve the issue. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: The problem came back for me too - I think it may be a chrome dns cache problem